# Is there an R function to get a table of expected counts?

Tags: r

I have the following table of heartburn symptoms and response to two different medications:

```
           Medication
Symptoms    Drug A Drug B Totals
  Heartburn     64     92    156
  Normal       114     98    212
  Totals       178    190    368
```

I'm looking for an **R** function that goes through the following operations to get the *expected* counts:

```
                    Medication
Symptoms       Drug A                   Drug B               
Heartburn     156 * 178 / 368 = 75      156 * 190 / 368 = 81 
Normal        212 * 178 / 368 = 103     212 * 190 / 368 = 109
```

Ideally the display would even be optionally as follows:

```
           Medication
Symptoms       Drug A   Drug B    Totals
  Heartburn     64(75)   92(81)    156
  Normal       114(103)  98(109)   212
  Totals       178      190        368
```

It's not too much to ask, is it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Example from `?chisq.test`:

```
 M <- as.table(rbind(c(762, 327, 468), c(484, 239, 477)))
 dimnames(M) <- list(gender = c("F", "M"),
                     party = c("Democrat","Independent", "Republican"))
 Xsq <- chisq.test(M)  # Prints test summary
```

I think the `$expected` component of the result is what you want:

```
 Xsq$expected
 ##       party
 ## gender Democrat Independent Republican
 ##      F 703.6714    319.6453   533.6834
 ##      M 542.3286    246.3547   411.3166
```

The beginning of your preferred display:

```
M2 <- M; 
M2[] <- paste(M,paste0("(",round(Xsq$expected),")"))
##      party
## gender Democrat  Independent Republican
##      F 762 (704) 327 (320)   468 (534) 
##      M 484 (542) 239 (246)   477 (411)
```

See also `?addmargins`

Comment: Awesome solution! I love it.

Answer (score 4):

Here are some alternatives:

**1) outer** Use `outer` to produce the expected values and then put that together with the original table and parens using `sprintf`.  `noquote` can be used to display it without quote marks:

```
mm <- m
mm[-3,-3] <- matrix(sprintf("%3.0f(%.0f)", m, outer(m[, 3], m[3, ]) / m[3,3]), 3)[-3,-3]
```

giving:

```
> noquote(mm)
           Medication
Symptoms    Drug A   Drug B   Total
  Heartburn  64(75)   92(81)  156  
  Normal    114(103)  98(109) 212  
  Totals    178      190      368
```

**2) gmodels::CrossTable**  This function is specifically aimed at producing crosstabulation tables with expected counts and other statistics:

```
library(gmodels)
CrossTable(m[-3, -3], expected = TRUE, prop.r = FALSE, prop.c = FALSE, 
                        prop.t = FALSE, prop.chisq = FALSE)
```

giving:

```
   Cell Contents
|-------------------------|
|                       N |
|              Expected N |
|-------------------------|


Total Observations in Table:  368 


             | Medication 
    Symptoms |    Drug A |    Drug B | Row Total | 
-------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
   Heartburn |        64 |        92 |       156 | 
             |    75.457 |    80.543 |           | 
-------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
      Normal |       114 |        98 |       212 | 
             |   102.543 |   109.457 |           | 
-------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
Column Total |       178 |       190 |       368 | 
-------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|


Statistics for All Table Factors


Pearson's Chi-squared test 
------------------------------------------------------------
Chi^2 =  5.85     d.f. =  1     p =  0.0156 

Pearson's Chi-squared test with Yates' continuity correction 
------------------------------------------------------------
Chi^2 =  5.35     d.f. =  1     p =  0.0207
```

**3) descr::CrossTable** This is similar to gmodels::CrossTable but the output is slightly different.

```
library(descr)
CrossTable(m[-3,-3], prop.r = FALSE, prop.c = FALSE, prop.t = FALSE,
    prop.chisq = FALSE, expected = TRUE)
```

giving:

```
   Cell Contents 
|-------------------------|
|                       N | 
|              Expected N | 
|-------------------------|

====================================
             Medication
Symptoms     Drug A   Drug B   Total
------------------------------------
Heartburn        64       92     156
               75.5     80.5        
------------------------------------
Normal          114       98     212
              102.5    109.5        
------------------------------------
Total           178      190     368
====================================
```

**Note:** We used this as the input, `m`:

```
m <- matrix(c(64, 114, 178, 92, 98, 190, 156, 212, 368), 3, 
  dimnames = list(Symptoms = c("Heartburn", "Normal", "Totals"),
                  Medication = c("Drug A", "Drug B", "Total")))
```